# Logitech MX Keys is detected as of type mouse in battery widget

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, sonoma, widgets

Unfortunately the battery widget of Sonoma 14.2 detects the keyboard Logitech MX Keys as of type mouse. The widget shows a mouse icon:

[image]

Can this icon be changed?

Comment: I have a MX keys USB receiver and mouse and keyboard and my Mac on Sonoma 14.2 doesn't show any battery level. Did you install any third party software for the keyboard? Are you using the USB receiver or bluetooth?

Comment: I'm not using the USB receiver and also no Logi Options+. This worked for me out-of-the-box except the visual side effect.

Comment: I very much don’t recommend installing Logitech software. Out of the box is the way to go IMO.